# Running a java application in a windows frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to learn Java by creating a simple text-based "game".
It's going pretty good so far, but I want to run the game in a window instead of the console (Netbeans 8.0 in my case).

I've looked online on how to do this and I see a lot of results with JFrame, but I'm not seeing the JFrame appear at all.

My code is as follows:

**Main**

```
package helloworld;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        StartGame startGame = new StartGame();
        Play play = new Play();

        startGame.main();
        play.main();
    }
}
```

**Window**

```
package helloworld;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window {
    private static void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorld");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The classes startGame and play are just doing some calculations with numbers so they don't matter.

I'm not getting any error massages, it's just not showing a window.

Comment: `JFrame frame = new JFrame("HellowWorld");` [Creates a new, initially _invisible_ Frame with the specified title.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame(java.lang.String))

Comment: call `frame.setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and valid fo all [Top-Level Contianers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) aren't visible by default, in compare with JComponents
- you have to call `JFrame.setVisible(true)` after all `JComponents` are added to `JFrame`, and sizing is done
- also read [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Wouldn't I have to call the Window class aswell? I'd assume I need to call the class for it to actually perform the code.

Comment: reason to post links to Oracle tutorial in my answer (for working code examples), note Window is reserved Java words awt.Window, change this name to MyWindow

Comment: Ok I got the window showing up, and also renamed it so it doesn't cause any conflicts. 1 last thing: the "game" is still running in the console of netbeans. Any idea on how I would get it in the newly created window?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have'nt set the frame to be visible or given it a size. Use

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(300,400;) //whatever size you want
```

Comment: Don't suggest `setSize()`. prefer `pack()`.

Comment: @Rubinum What's the harm to teach a good way? Is pack a difficult method to learn.

Comment: Braj I didnt want to go into explaining the importance of LayoutManagers which is why I didnt suggest pack(). As Braj said you can use frame.pack() and frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)) which will try to resize each component to its preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `frame.setVisible(true);`. This will make the window visible.

[JFrame#setVisible JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)